# How to increase/decrease height of Sublime status bar?

Tags: user-interface, themes, sublimetext3

I was successful at modifying the `sidebar_container` and `tabset_control` of Material Theme except the status bar. It is a bit too big for me and I want to adjust the height of it like Piatto's (also the width/height of button if possible).

Material Theme: (modified, except status bar)
[image]

Piatto Dark Theme:
[image]

How do I set height/width of the status bar? (and also buttons on it, if possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try add the following code to your .sublime-theme file. Modify the values in the "content_margin" to adjust the height.

```
{
    "class": "status_bar",
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 0, 0]
},
{
    "class": "status_button",
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 0, 0],
    "min_size": [75, 0]
}
```

Or add the following in the user setting:

```
"material_theme_small_statusbar": true
```

Comment: the last line is what i needed